# Creating new Pandas DataFrame based on two parameters

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, merge

This is my very first time asking a question:)

I have on Dataframe with company code (GVKEY) and for each company a set of dates with corresponding credit rating. I have another Dataframe with GVKEYs and a set of dates with corresponding financial ratios. I would like to create a new Dataframe where the companies, the dates and the ratio match.

For now I have tried a for loop, looping only trough the same company in order to avoid looping over the whole dataset. Would their be a faster way of doing it?

[DF with credit ratings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccHHq.png)

[DF with financial ratios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ztskd.png)

[DF with financial ratios matched with credit ratings, GVKEY and dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7qUp.png)

Comment: Hey @culpeo, welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you please attach a minimal example input Dataframe and an example output Dataframe to help others to help you?

Comment: Thank for your comment, I have added this. Hope it makes it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use pandas.merge like this.

pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on = ['company code', 'date'], right_on = ['company code', 'date'])

Comment: Thank you very much! It works wonderfully. (Feel a bit stupid with my for loops ^^)